# VBA DAO Accessing Excel 2010 like database

Tags: vba, excel-2010, dao

I am trying to use DAO to write some VBA into Excel 2010. I want to be able to access an excel 2010 workbook like a database. I am trying to open a workbook instead of a mdb file. Is there any way I can use DAO with an excel workbook instead of an actual database?

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim SQL As String

SQL = "SELECT * From [DataSheet$]"

Set db = OpenDatabase(ThisWorkbook.FullName)
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(SQL)

'displays the first record and first field
MsgBox rst.Fields(0)

'close the objects
rst.Close
db.Close

'destroy the variables
Set rst = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

I borrowed code from here http://www.excel-spreadsheet.com/vba/dao_ado.htm

Comment: If the code you post is not working please explain HOW it's not working. FWIW though I don't think you can access an *open* workbook as a database. I think you need to work with a closed workbook (saved file). The already opened workbook will probably be file-locked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out my issue. Using the code below you can access an excel file and treat it like a database.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnConnect_Click()
  Dim dataConection As New ADODB.Connection
  Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset
  Dim SQL As String
  Dim DBPath As String
  Dim connectionString As String

  DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName 'Refering the sameworkbook as Data Source

  'You can provide the full path of your external file as shown below
  connectionString = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';"

  'Open connection
  dataConection.Open connectionString

  'Create SQL query
  SQL = "SELECT * From [DataSheet$]"

  'Open record set (query or table, connection)
  mrs.Open SQL, dataConection

  Do While Not mrs.EOF
    Debug.Print "  " & mrs!Name
    mrs.MoveNext
  Loop

  mrs.Close

  'Close Connection
  dataConection.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, but that's ADO, not DAO. DAO can work, but if you don't explain the problem you're having...

Comment: Sorry, the problem was that I was trying to open a workbook file with OpenDatabase and it gave me an application error.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you *can* connect to Excel workbooks using DAO by extending the arguments of [DAO.OpenDatabase()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/dbengine-opendatabase-method-dao):

```
Dim conn As Object, db As Object, rst As Object

Set conn = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120")  

' EXCEL OLDER VERSION
Set db = conn.OpenDatabase("C:\Path\To\Excel_Workbook.xls", False, True, "Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;")

' EXCEL CURRENT VERSION
Set db = conn.OpenDatabase("C:\Path\To\Excel_Workbook.xlsx", False, True, "Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;")

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]")

MsgBox rst.Fields(0)

rst.Close
db.Close

Set db = Nothing
Set conn = Nothing
Set rst = Nothing
```

Comment: c'est parfait !